# google.visualization.LineChart haxis is overlapping with vaxis

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization

[image: overlapping axis labels]

As you can see from this image, my axis labels are a bit too tight.  I have tried many things to fix this but am still not finding a solution.  Can I add css to these or is there another solution than css?

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this to your options:

```
 hAxis: { viewWindow: { min: new Date(2015, 0, 15) } }
```

You'll have to experiment to find a date that adds some space on the left without a tick value on the leftmost position on the axis.  Note that month indices in JavaScript start with 0 for January.

You can also try adding this:

```
hAxis: { gridlines: { count: -1 } }
```

And then you can experiment with the new date formatting options, which are documented here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#axesgridlinesticks